# Error : CakePHP 1.3 import component to shell

Tags: shell, cakephp, cron, cakephp-1.3

Hi currently i am trying to import a components to shell and here is my code

```
<?php
App::import('Component', 'OptimalPayment');

class PushEftShell extends Shell {
    var $uses = array('User' , 'Payment');

    function main() {
        $OptimalPayment = OptimalPaymentComponent();
        $Organsation = $this->Organisation->find('all', array(
            'fields' => array('id', 'name'),
            'contain' => array(
                'ContactPerson', 'BankDetail', 'Address', 'Phone'
            )
        ));
    }
}
?>
```

and im having this error message

```
Fatal error: Class 'Component' not found in C:\web\appName\app\controllers\components\optimal_payment.php on line 24
```

what's wrong with my import?

TIA

Comment: what's in line 24 in `C:\web\appName\app\controllers\components\optimal_payment.php` ?

Comment: thats the interesting stuff on this line of codes.. i only have 22line of codes and the error is pointing to line 24

Comment: You sure you are looking at `C:\web\appName\app\controllers\components\optimal_payment.php` line 24 and **NOT** your shell code?

Comment: optimal_payment.php line 24 contains this `class OptimalPaymentComponent extends Component {`

Answer (score 1):

In CakePHP 1.3 you should extend your component class by `Object`. It means you should write as following:

```
class OptimalPaymentComponent extends Object{
.............
}
```